# Android Displaying Version Name on Splash Screen Using Gradle

Tags: android, version-control, gradle, build.gradle

I am developing an Android app using a splash screen.

I want to display the app's version name at the bottom of the layout, but I am using Gradle and version name/version code isn't in *manifest.xml* file, they are in the *build.gradle* file.

How can I access the version code?

Comment: They will be in the generated manifests. The only reason you don't put them in your own manifest is that we generate different ones for different variants so putting the values in Gradle provide more flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you want to get it programmatically?

```
PackageInfo package = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
version = package.versionName;
versionCode = package.versionCode;
```